# In R Overlap spatial polygons dataframe (spdf) and summarise number of features of 1st spdf overlapped by 2nd spdf

Tags: r, spatial, arcgis, r-sf

I have tried several sources but no luck. Please see my codes below and I state the problem at the end of codes. I have created random hexagonal grids over large areas and wanted to summarize how many of them fall under features of 2nd spatial polygon data frame.

```
library (sf)
library(dplyr)
library(raster)

# load 2nd spdf
```

Read ibra [polygons](http://www.environment.gov.au/fed/catalog/search/resource/downloadData.page?uuid=%7B8B9E3F42-9856-4487-AE9E-C76A322809A1%7D#) as sf object. To download paste 'Interim Biogeographic Regionalisation for Australia (IBRA)' in the search item then click on 'Interim Biogeographic Regionalisation for Australia (IBRA), Version 7 (Regions)'

```
ibra <- st_read("ibra7_subregions.shp")
ibra <- st_transform(ibra, crs = 4326)

# ibra has >2000 features (i.e., rows) for 89 regions of same name, group them together
ibraGrid <- ibra %>%
  group_by(REG_NAME_7) %>%
  st_sf() %>%
  mutate(cellid = row_number()) %>%
  summarise()

colnames(ibraGrid)[1] <- "id"

# crop ibra to specific boundary
box <- extent(112,155,-45,-10)
ibraGrid <- st_crop(ibraGrid, box)


# make dataframe of spatial grid (1st spdf)
ran.p <- st_sample(au, size = 1040)
```

Load shp of au from [here](http://data.daff.gov.au/anrdl/metadata_files/pa_nsaasr9nnd_02211a04.xml) then click on "nsaasr9nnd_02211a04es_geo___.zip".

```
au <- st_read("aust_cd66states.shp")
au <- st_transform(au, crs = 4326)

# create grid around multipoints
rand_sampl_Grid <- ran.p %>%
  st_make_grid(cellsize = 0.1, square = F) %>%
  st_intersection(au) %>%
  st_cast("MULTIPOLYGON") %>%
  st_sf() %>%
  mutate(cellid = row_number())


# sampled grid per ibra region
density_per_ib_grid <- ibraGrid %>%
  st_join(rand_sampl_Grid) %>% 
  mutate(overlap = ifelse(!is.na(id), 1, 0)) %>%
  group_by(cellid) %>%
  summarize(num_sGrid = sum(overlap))
```

Everything worked well. But, I expected that the length of `View(density_per_ib_grid$num_sGrid)` would be equal to the number of features in `ibraGrid` (i.e., 89). Currently, `View(density_per_ib_grid$num_sGrid)` has length of features equal to `rand_sample_Grid` (i.e., ~1040). In addition, I want to repeat the process for 100 times so that `num_sGrid` would be the mean of 100 iterations.

The above codes worked desirably using larger spdf (which is ibraGrid in this casae) created from coordinates. Any suggestions/feedback will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The second link to the API doesn't seem to work

Comment: I have updated the link.

Comment: My computer can't finish the computation, maybe try this at yours: You're defining the CRS in `st_read`, but this doesn't transform and the ibra data are also not in 4326. Try `au = st_transform(au,4326)` and `au = st_transform(au,4326)` after import with both, Ibra and states.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I did `st_transform` for both `au`, and `ibra` after they were read in the memory and before doing any further analysis, but still the output is same. `au <- st_transform(au, 4326); ibra <- st_transform(ibra, 4326)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the solution. The last codes section in the above question should be as:

```
richness_per_ib_grid <- st_intersection(ibraGrid, rand_sampl_Grid) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  count()

out <- as.data.frame(int.result)[,-3] # print output as data frame.
```

#### Therefore the complete answer for the question above should be:

```
library (sf)
library(dplyr)
library(raster)

# load 2nd spdf
```

Read ibra [polygons](http://www.environment.gov.au/fed/catalog/search/resource/downloadData.page?uuid=%7B8B9E3F42-9856-4487-AE9E-C76A322809A1%7D#) as sf object. To download paste 'Interim Biogeographic Regionalisation for Australia (IBRA)' in the search item then click on 'Interim Biogeographic Regionalisation for Australia (IBRA), Version 7 (Regions)'

```
ibra <- st_read("ibra7_subregions.shp")
ibra <- st_transform(ibra, crs = 4326)

# ibra has >2000 features (i.e., rows) for 89 regions of same name, group them together
ibraGrid <- ibra %>%
  group_by(REG_NAME_7) %>%
  st_sf() %>%
  summarise()

colnames(ibraGrid)[1] <- "id"

# crop ibra to specific boundary
box <- extent(112,155,-45,-10)
ibraGrid <- st_crop(ibraGrid, box)


# make dataframe of spatial grid (1st spdf)
ran.p <- st_sample(au, size = 1040)
```

Load shp of au from [here](http://data.daff.gov.au/anrdl/metadata_files/pa_nsaasr9nnd_02211a04.xml) then click on "nsaasr9nnd_02211a04es_geo___.zip".

```
au <- st_read("aust_cd66states.shp")
au <- st_transform(au, crs = 4326)

# create grid around multipoints
rand_sampl_Grid <- ran.p %>%
  st_make_grid(cellsize = 0.1, square = F) %>%
  st_intersection(au) %>%
  st_cast("MULTIPOLYGON") %>%
  st_sf()


# sampled grid per ibra region
density_per_ib_grid <- <- st_intersection(ibraGrid, rand_sampl_Grid) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  count()

out <- as.data.frame(int.result)[,-3] # print output as data frame.
```